# Material UI's "Select" Component doesn't reset value after clicking Clear form by using autofill values

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, material-ui

I've been struggling with a strange behavior  that I think is more like a bug of the select component itself. I just want to make sure that I'm not doing anything wrong or am not missing some properties to set.

Okay the thing is, I'm using `material ui` and when I use the `autofill` feature provided by the browser everything seem to work fine (you have to fill up all the information and chose a different value from `Select` component) and click submit, then reload the sandbox and you will be able to see the autofill option when focusing an input.

[image]

next, When I click on Clear form

[image]

all the values are being reseted except the value in the select component.

[image: ![enter image description here]

when I use the `native` option for the `Select` works fine but I'm losing the chance to use the `Select` as It should be

Attached is the example with the code

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-hugle-dxuvj3?file=/src/App.js:1098-1462

Comment: Because, In mui-select, you are using "Canada" as a default option

Comment: mm that's not the issue, the issue is that is not taking the default value after clearing the form